# google image search API for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, google-image-search

I am creating an application in which I am trying to implement google image search using Google- image-search API. I refer this [google API link] (https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/) . But I have one problem, on that page, mentioned (DEPRECATED). So can I use this API or I should use other API? Can anyone knows about this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deprecated means it is older one also it means that there exist new version code for that. [Check this out](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).

**Example:**

[For example](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/customizingresults), in order to change our search engine from webresults-based to image-based, we can utilize the `defaultToImageSearch` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

If APIs are deprecated they may work for now but not with full features and may go offline in near future.

If you go to  https://developers.google.com/image-search/

It says its Deprecated and the number of requests are limited now.

```
Important: The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011.     
It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to upgrade to the Custom Search API, which now supports image search.
```

Here is the link to Custom Search API

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to create custom search engine

Comment: @Radhu.: Ok but its written there that you can use it for `image search` also so i just thought to share.